# AJAX not getting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamically jquery created item dropdown. I have an ajax call that gets the item details (price, unit) whenever the dropdown changes.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#create_item', function(){
    var item_id = $('#create_item').val();
    alert(item_id);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo base_url('Create_controller/getItem'); ?>',
        data : { item_id : item_id },
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){
            var item_data = data;
            alert(data);
            $.each(item_data, function(index, value){
                if(index == 0){
                    $('#create_unit').val(value.unit);
                    $('#create_price').val(value.price);
                }
            })
        },
        error : function(errorw){
            alert('Error');
        }
   });
});
```

Here is my controller

```
public function getItemDetails(){
    $item_id = $this->input->post('item_id');
    $item_details = $this->create_model->getItemDetails($item_id);
    echo json_encode($item_details);
}
```

And here is my model

```
function getItemDetails($item_id){
    $this->db->select('unit, price');
    $this->db->from('item');
    $this->db->where('id', $item_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I know that my `data` is empty because it alerts an empty string. I also know that there should be values as I've tried `print_r($this->create->model->getItemDetails($item_id)` and there are values returned.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you're in Chrome you can open the developer console by right clicking the page and clicking "Inspect". You can then navigate to the Network tab to see the actual data returned from the request directly. Also, try console logging the data, instead of alerting. Maybe that'll provide more insight in to your problem

Comment: Check console and debug as said above. Beside this have a look on your success handling. From my sight your $.each is not giving desired effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very simple mistake. I replaced

```
url : '<?php echo base_url('Create_controller/getItem'); ?>',
```

to

```
url : '<?php echo base_url('Create_controller/getItemDetails'); ?>',
```

since `getItemDetails` is my controller method